# No visible interface for @LWWFirstController declares the selector initWithStyle

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I am getting the error "No visible interface for @LWWFirstController declares the selector initWithStyle".  I have written similar code for setting up my Navigation Controller and it worked fine, but I can't seem to find what is causing this error.  I have looked on StackOverFlow for similar issues but none fit, I'm using the correct method for it.  Does anyone have in clue?  Here is my code below.

```
#import "LWWAppDelegate.h"
#import "LWWFirstLevelController.h"

@implementation LWWAppDelegate 

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize navController;




#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:     (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

LWWFirstLevelController *first = [[LWWFirstLevelController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                      initWithRootViewController:first];
[self.window addSubview:navController.view];

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

Comment: Can you add "LWWFirstLevelController.h" to your question - you might be getting a circular import by including the app delegate's .h file again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It basically says you didn't implement `initWithStyle` method in your `LWWFirstLevelController`.

Are you sure it is a subclass of `UITableViewController`?

Comment: Ah dang it!  Your right Selkie..I jacked up the header file i had this:
@interface LWWFirstLevelController : UIViewController

Comment: I changed it to this and it cleared it up.  Thanks for pointing that out Selkie!
@interface LWWFirstLevelController : UITableViewController